# Selecting blank lines in draft impossible

Tags: bug, status-declined, ios-app

I just posted a question (from my laptop) in this format:

> I have a problem. It looks like this:
>
> What should I do about it?

I then opened the app to add a photo from my phone, into the gap I'd left for it. Trying to do this, I found it's impossible (very difficult?) to select a mid-post, blank line in the editor.

Standard iOS behaviour is the same as a desktop, that tapping at any point on a blank line puts the cursor at the start of the line (See Mail/Notes.) Shouldn't the SE app do the same?

Comment: Slightly related, but why did you need to switch to the app from the browser to upload a picture?  Was there a reason, or was there no reason you did it?

Comment: @psubsee2003: the browser was on my laptop - sorry, I'll clarify! (And, of course, it was easiest to type my long question on my laptop, but then add the photo from my phone.)

Comment: So this doesn't really have anything to do with prior use of laptop and browser and switching to phone, but simply it's difficult/impossible to select a position to add an image when on the iOS app?

Comment: @James I guess the only relevance was to explain why I didn't add the image as I was writing the post. I'll edit in the morning, if someone else doesn't get there first!

Comment: It sounds like if you use the app and apply an image as you insert content then all is ok, but if you try to go back over and insert into previous content (such as blank lines etc) then it's too fiddly to manage.

Comment: I see the behavior.  No clear reason why it's happening but I see it.  The text view from iOS7+ is an incredibly complex beast that makes me very sad.

Comment: If you long press to get the loupe you can hover over the location where you want the cursor.  You won't see it, but it'll be there.  When you type it'll appear.

Comment: @Brian: Yeah, that works. That's a bit rubbish...potential iOS bug?

Comment: Probably an iOS bug but it could just be because of the way we are using the text view.  It's hard to say the exact cause without a lot of unpleasant research and experimentation.

Answer (score 1):

This is an unfortunate bug in iOS and there are no obvious fixes.  Sometimes when selecting a blank line (which is not easy to do) the caret disappears.

It appears to be triggered by logic in the incredibly complex `-[UITextSelectionView updateSelectionRects]` function which currently exceeds my debugging capabilities to figure out.

The good news is that the blank line can be selected, there's just no indication that it is. :/